# WIFI on boot, but disconnect immediatly

Tags: wireless, 14.10, rfkill

I've got an asus N550JV running Ubuntu 14.10.

I've replaced Unity with i3 and am having networking problems ever since.

Right now my WIFI is connected as soon as i3 loads up, but it disconnects after 1 second. Ethernet stays up in the meantime though.

## Some details:

```
@dev-Laptop:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: yes
3: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
@dev-Laptop:~$ sudo cat /etc/network/interfaces
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
        wpa-ssid ssid
        wpa-psk password
```

If i add `rfkill unblock all` to `/etc/rc.local` then it won't boot with any networking at all, allthough `rfkill list all` shows that everything is unblocked then.

In the above configuration:

```
@dev-Laptop:~$ sudo ifup wlan0 -v
\Configuring interface wlan0=wlan0 (inet)
run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/ethtool
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
wpa_supplicant: wpa-driver nl80211,wext (default)
wpa_supplicant: /sbin/wpa_supplicant -s -B -P /var/run/wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid -i wlan0 -D nl80211,wext -C /var/run/wpa_supplicant
Starting /sbin/wpa_supplicant...
wpa_supplicant: creating sendsigs omission pidfile: /run/sendsigs.omit.d/wpasupplicant.wpa_supplicant.wlan0.pid
wpa_supplicant: ctrl_interface socket located at /var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0
wpa_supplicant: configuring network block -- 0
wpa_supplicant: wpa-ssid "ssid" -- OK
wpa_supplicant: wpa-psk ***** -- OK
wpa_supplicant: enabling network block 0 -- OK

dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.wlan0.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.wlan0.leases wlan0    
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.2.4
Copyright 2004-2012 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

RTNETLINK answers: Operation not possible due to RF-kill
Listening on LPF/wlan0/80:86:f2:52:48:15
Sending on   LPF/wlan0/80:86:f2:52:48:15
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x174b3ce0)
send_packet: Network is down
dhclient.c:1993: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
receive_packet failed on wlan0: Network is down
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6 (xid=0x174b3ce0)
send_packet: Network is down
dhclient.c:1993: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 9 (xid=0x174b3ce0)
send_packet: Network is down
dhclient.c:1993: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
DHCPDISCOVER on wlan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11 (xid=0x174b3ce0)
send_packet: Network is down
dhclient.c:1993: Failed to send 300 byte long packet over wlan0 interface.
```

Any ideas where to take it from here? I've googled about for some time and have manager to get a connection working through wpa_cli but that doesn't persist.

The wifi is secured with WPA/PSK2.

Answer (score 0):

I am quite confident that as soon as boot up is complete and the helper module *asus_nb_wmi* loads, it turns *OFF* the wireless; please note:

> 2: phy0: Wireless LAN
>    Soft blocked: yes
>    Hard blocked: yes

Let's try a driver parameter. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=1"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi
modprobe asus_nb_wmi
exit
```

It may take a reboot. Any improvement? If not, repeat the above sequence but use 4 instead of 1:

```
sudo -i
echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4"  >  /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb_wmi.conf
modprobe -r asus_nb_wmi
modprobe asus_nb_wmi
exit
```

Comment: Sorry for my late response, the app wasn't logged in. Both options didn't help.